Reference enum members in XAML elements
I want to make a ComboBox whose elements are a subset of the members of an enum type. If I once knew the syntax for this, I can't remember it now!
I'm basically looking for the markup equivalent of throwing this into the constructor:
        cboState.Items.Add(InvoiceState.Ready);
        cboState.Items.Add(InvoiceState.Waiting);
        cboState.Items.Add(InvoiceState.Finished);

Simply binding to Enum.GetValues doesn't work because there are values I don't want to include. If these were in attribute values, I could use {x:Static core:InvoiceState.Ready}, etc. But they're not attribute values.
            <ComboBox Name="cboState">
                <!-- what goes here? -->
                <core:InvoiceState>Ready</core:InvoiceState> <!-- does not work -->
            </ComboBox>


While <core:InvoiceState>Ready</core:InvoiceState> etc. should work, you may also use the x:Static extension with element syntax like this:
<ComboBox>
    <x:Static Member="core:InvoiceState.Ready"/>
    <x:Static Member="core:InvoiceState.Waiting"/>
    <x:Static Member="core:InvoiceState.Finished"/>
</ComboBox>

The syntax is mentioned in the Remarks section of the x:Static Markup Extension documentation.

Maybe I misunderstood you, but ENUM should work without problems as in your example:
namespace Core
{
    public enum InvoiceState { None, Ready, Waiting, Finished, Some}
}

        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  MinWidth="50">
            <core:InvoiceState>Ready</core:InvoiceState>
            <core:InvoiceState>Waiting</core:InvoiceState>
            <core:InvoiceState>Finished</core:InvoiceState>
        </ComboBox>

No warnings:

Runtime:

P.S. Even more. String to Enum and vice versa conversion is the default for WPF. Take a look at this example:
    public class InvoiceStateViewModel
    {
        public InvoiceState State { get; set; }
    }

    <UniformGrid>
        <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
            <core:InvoiceStateViewModel/>
        </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    MinWidth="50"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding State}">
            <sys:String>Ready</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Waiting</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Finished</sys:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding State}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </UniformGrid>


Curious. When I tried that, I got build errors. Hmm...

@JonathanGilbert
I have supplemented my answer with a second example. Look at it.

That's fair, but I don't like the "looseness" of just throwing strings in and letting it convert at runtime. :-) I am a strong advocate for type safety!

@JonathanGilbert
It is important to understand that for such declaration <core:InvoiceState>Ready</core:InvoiceState> the same converter from string to target type is also used as for Binding. The purpose of the second example is to demonstrate the converter's work.

And that conversion takes place at runtime?

@JonathanGilbert
It happens in runtime when the InitializeComponent() method is called.

When you add strings to the ComboBox, the automatic type conversion to/from InvoiceState will of course always occur when SelectedItem="{Binding State}" updates its target or source property, i.e. both binding directions. There is however no performance or other relevant impact.

I'll add to @Clemens
There is a difference in performance, of course. But it's calculated, compared to the overall speed of the WPF GUI, in hundredths of a percent. It's like "getting a one-dollar discount when buying a Mercedes." And you will receive this discount only when you click on the Item in the ComboBox.

Hmm, so it's not possible to be type-safe entirely in XAML, and if you want a build error if you have a typo in your enum member name, the only option is to do it from the code-behind? I could have sworn that a typo in the XAML would produce a build error, but I just loaded up a project and tested it and it builds without errors. The IDE is kind enough to warn on it, but that's not the same thing as type safety. :-P

@JonathanGilbert
XAML is not compiled. It can be somewhat compressed in BAML, but this is not compilation, it is just size optimization. XAML is an extension of XML. A rough analogy is XML deserialization. XML can have an error, but it will be revealed only at runtime. The same is with XAML. Pay attention to the behavior of the GUI in debug. Editing XAML immediately changes the presentation. Recompilation (new project build) is not needed for this.
